# My routes file doesn't match expected result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm working my way through Michael Hartl's "learn enough" RoR lessons and am at the point where we're working with authenticating users via sessions.

[Per the lesson](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#code-sessions_resource), I've just run `rails generate controller Sessions new` and nothing blew chunks:

```
$ rails generate controller Sessions new
Running via Spring preloader in process 4407
      create  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
       route  get 'sessions/new'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/sessions
      create    app/views/sessions/new.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/sessions.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/sessions.scss
```

However, there's a discrepancy between what the lesson says routes.rb should look like and what it actually does look like.

**Expected result** in routes.rb, as implied by the lesson:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root   'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

**Actual result** in routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  root                'static_pages#home'
  get '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  resources :users
end
```

Am I missing something obvious? Why the difference?

I feel like there's a missing chapter between here and the last one, which only explains the really high level difference between browser-close-ending sessions and cookie-expired sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The reason for the discrepancy is that `rails generate controller Sessions new` only generates the GET route @vnbrs mentioned.

The lesson calls for 3 routes that need to be supported: a `GET` request to the login form, a `POST` request to create the session, and a `DELETE` request to destroy the session.

Those need to be added to routes.rb manually:

```
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

Beginner's disorientation, I couldn't see the forest for the trees and broke my brain. (P.S. I don't recommend trying to tackle this tutorial discontinuously over a series of months...your brain does NOT pick up where it left off.)

Answer (score 0):

You ran `rails generate controller Sessions new`, which means you want to generate a controller with the `new` action only. By default, `new` generates the view route (GET) and the actual resource creation route (POST).

To create the controller and routes following the CRUD pattern, you should run `rails generate controller Sessions`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that would be the case, but here's why I'm confused: rails generate controller Sessions new is what the lesson calls for. https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#code-sessions_resource